# Extjs Slider from from right to left

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

How to change Ext.slider.Single to work from right to left ?

That means that max value is when slider is on the left, and when user drags it to the riggt value is going down, and reach minimum value when it is on the right.

Comment: what does your code look like?

Comment: It does not look like :) I mean I didn't override Ext.slider.Single class, I've only used it by creating a component of  xtype: slider, and didn't find how to change this default behaivour.